# Can I play Attack on Titan Without PS

Tags: attack-on-titan-2

Can I play the Attack on Titan game without PS+. I don't want to buy it because I don't have PS+

Answer (score 1):

[Attack on Titan](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP4108-CUSA03804_00-AT1NAHDDGAME0000) and [Attack on Titan 2](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP4108-CUSA08956_00-AT2NAHDDGAME0000) both have single player modes that do not require a PS+ subscription in order to play.

Both games note that online play is optional, which does require a PS+ subscription to access the multiple online features